# How can I make my React Native app go into the "fetch" method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, xmlhttprequest

I have a question for people using React Native. Currently I'm trying to retrieve simple JSON data with the following url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts The problem I'm having is that I can't get my program to go through the "fetch method "although recognized by React Native, can someone help me?

My current React Native application with LOGS

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect")

        const result = fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.json) // should display the data in the logs
        })
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
        });

        console.log(result);
    })

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Mon test</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: on the first `then` you should return response.json(); and second one you could have your data?

Comment: I tried also, I don't know why my application can't go inside the "fetch" method. Is that a config issue ? Thanks again for the help, I appreciate it https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/44/7/1604244336-screenshot-2020-11-01-162518.png

Comment: Please check how to use `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch. inside second `then` the console should give you your data =)

Answer (score 0):

you can use axios to fetch data
First install axios via `npm i axios`
Then import axios ==> `import axios from 'axios'`
This is an exemple:

```
useEffect(async () => {
const result = await axios(
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

console.log(result.data);},[]);
```

Comment: Thanks but I already tried with axios, I think it's a config problem but I don't know where to allow http requests from outside of the application. Any idea ? https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/44/7/1604243760-screenshot-2020-11-01-161535.png

Answer (score 0):

I just installed another device and it works well, thanks again for the help, I appreciate it !